# /index/ in URLs - Required?

Tags: routing

In particular, I'm working on a Magento site with a custom module that is only accessible if you include `/index/` at the end of the module's frontend route. So the route is setup like this:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
       <mycompany_mymodule>
           <use>standard</use>
           <args>
               <module>Mycompany_Mymodule</module>
               <frontName>shortname</frontName>
           </args>
       </mycompany_mymodule>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

On some servers and local installs of the site, `example.com/shortname/` works. However, on others you get a *404* unless you go to `example.com/shortname/index/`

This leads me to a few questions:

1. Any idea what causes the requirement for `/index/` in the route on some servers?
2. As a whole, are "index" as a default controller and "index" as a default action hard coded into Magento or is it something that can be customized per module?
3. Particularly *where* in the code does Magento look for "index" controllers and actions?

Answer (score 3):

`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::fetchDefault()`

The above function call from `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::match()`

set's the default values on the Front Controller. These defaults are then retrieved while the standard router (similarly other routers) are trying to match a request to a controller class and action.

```
public function fetchDefault()
{
    $this->getFront()->setDefault(array(
        'module' => 'core',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index'
    ));
}
```

I think this should answer 2,3 for you. Not sure about the 1st.